# How to play file without using external video file

Tags: c#

I want to have a video play within my program, however i dont want to refer to a video that is outside of my program, is there a way to have the video embedded into the program.

I have tried refering to resources of the application and adding video there however this doesn't seem to be possible.

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Properties.Resources.INTRO

I would like to have the video play from the application and not have to know where the video is on the computer as this is something that will change from computer to computer.

Comment: You can get the current path of your program (how depends on the project type) so the fact that path will change from pc to pc isn't a problem if the file is in the same or sub directory ...

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you can always include video files in the project and reference them through that. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/22d51c4b-7ceb-487a-91ed-462a6d1e13fd/c-winforms-embed-video-as-resource?forum=winforms

Comment: it should be possible to read a resource out of your own binary, load it into memory, and get its stream. is that what your asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like axWindowsMediaPlayer can't play video out of stream. Is is appropriate to you to save resource video to temporary file and then play it?

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, Properties.Resources.INTRO);
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = fileName;
```